# Color entire row when condition is met

Tags: vba, excel, colors

[image: Green file]

What the code is doing is if Col X and Y contains dates, color entire row as yellow.
If only X contains a date, color entire row as red.
But if X and Y are empty, color it green. On the last condition.

I can't make my code work to color entire row if condition is met.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lrX As Long     'last row with a filled cell in column X
Dim lrY As Long     'last row with a filled cell in column Y
Dim lr As Long      'max of lrX and lrY
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

lrX = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrY = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(lrX, lrY)

For i = 2 To lr     'my data starts in row 1, otherwise change this
    If IsDate(ws.Range("X" & i).Value) Then
        If IsDate(ws.Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
          ws.Range("a" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow       'both X and Y have a date value, so Yellow
        Else
          ws.Range("a" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed        'only X has a date
        If (.Cells(i, 24).Value = "") And _
        (.Cells(i, 25).Value = "") Then
         .Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4  ' 4: Green
        End If
    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do something like this with a formula. You could modify the function to handle more logic and colors.

This will color the row green if the expression is true. You specify the color as RGB.

`=ColorRowIF(A1=B1, 1, 181, 0)`

Or in your case

`=ColorRowIF(IsDate(A1), 1, 181, 0)`

```vb
Public Function ColorRowIF(Condition As Boolean, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer) As String
    Dim row As Integer
    row = Application.Caller.row

    If Condition = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Evaluate "ColorRow(" & row & ", " & r & ", " & g & ", " & b & ")"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Evaluate "RemoveRowColor(" & row & ")"
    End If

    ColorRowIF = Condition
End Function


Public Sub ColorRow(row As Integer, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Rows(row).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)

End Sub

Public Sub RemoveRowColor(row As Integer)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.Rows(row).Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub


Function IsDate(CellDate As Date) As Boolean
    If CellDate >= 1 And CellDate <= #12/31/2199# Then
    ' 1 is equal to January 1, 1900
        IsDate = True
    Else
        IsDate = False
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Answer (score 0):

A few reasons why your code didn't work:

1. You have `If (.Cells(i, 24).Value = "") And (.Cells(i, 25).Value = "") Then` but you are missing the `With` statements of the `ws` object.
2. You have 3 x `If` and only 2 x `End If`.
3. You have `If IsDate(ws.Range("X" & i).Value) Then` as the first `If` criteria, so if the value in column "X" is not a date, you leave all the loops (since the other 2 x `If`s you have are being checked only if you pass this first `If`).

Try the code below (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lrX As Long     'last row with a filled cell in column X
Dim lrY As Long     'last row with a filled cell in column Y
Dim lr As Long      'max of lrX and lrY
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

lrX = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lrY = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(lrX, lrY)

With ws ' <-- added the with statement
    For i = 2 To lr     'my data starts in row 1, otherwise change this
        ' first check if both cells are empty
        If .Range("X" & i).Value = "" And .Range("Y" & i).Value = "" Then
            .Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4  ' 4: Green
        ElseIf IsDate(.Range("X" & i).Value) Then
            If IsDate(.Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
                .Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbYellow  'both X and Y have a date value, so Yellow
            Else
                .Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbRed  'only X has a date
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With
```